# No hard disk, Can't access BIOS. What do I do?

Tags: boot, bios

I have a Toshiba Sattelite P755 Laptop without a hard drive. Everytime I start the computer it immediately says

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
>   or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

Is it possible for me to boot Ubuntu from a flash drive or CD in my situation? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, why not try it?

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie to computer hardware, should I just burn a distro to a CD-R and start the computer with the disk in?

Comment: Yes - I use imgburn on windows or k3b on linux for that- or use  something like [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to unpack an iso to a flash drive to make it bootable. I'm starting to think your real question is "what do I do with a livecd iso?" ;)

Comment: That is all it will take, I have run my computer for a week checking out Ubuntu, I used a "live CD"

Answer (score 0):

As hard drives are the primary boot drives so your PC is not booting as it can't find appropriate files anywhere. However if you change the boot priority to USB Flash drive or CD/DVD then you can boot from those devices if you have a bootable media. Also you can override the boot menu and select the boot device from there also.